# Accessing values in list without names

Tags: r

I have the following list of named characters to use as a palette in ggplot2:

```
aa_palette <- c("#75041a", "#a50026", "#d73027", "#f46d43", "#fdae61", "#fee090", "#ffffbf", 
"#e0f3f8", "#aad0e5", "#abd9e9", "#74add1", "#4575b4", "#313695", "#2a167a", "#989898")
names(aa_palette) <- c("Asx", "Glx", "Ser", "Thr", "His", "Gly", "Arg", "Ala", "Tyr", "Val", 
"Met", "Phe", "Leu", "Ile", "Other")
```

However some of my plots have variables that don't correspond to the names in this list, so I want to extract just the values without needing to make a whole new object. I know I can do this for a single value using `[[]]` but I want to access multiple values in each graph, so I'm looking for a way to do this without having to access each value individually then `c()` them together. I've tried the following:

```
unlist(aa_palette, use.names = FALSE)
```

```
aa_palette[c("Asx", "Glx", "Ser")]
```

But both of these approaches still return the names of each element in the list. Is there a way to **access just the values** of some or all of the elements in the list without having to `[[]]` them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
unname(aa_palette)
```

**Update**

Based on comment below.

Alternatively you could create `aa_palette` as a list and then use your code above.
If you run `class(aa_palette)` on the above you will get `character` - i.e. a character vector which therefore can't be "unlisted".

```
aa_palette <- list("#75041a", "#a50026", "#d73027", "#f46d43", "#fdae61", "#fee090", "#ffffbf", 
"#e0f3f8", "#aad0e5", "#abd9e9", "#74add1", "#4575b4", "#313695", "#2a167a", "#989898")
names(aa_palette) <- c("Asx", "Glx", "Ser", "Thr", "His", "Gly", "Arg", "Ala", "Tyr", "Val", 
"Met", "Phe", "Leu", "Ile", "Other")
```

Then this works:

```
unlist(aa_palette, use.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: That works, thank you! Do you know why `unlist(aa_palette, use.names = FALSE)` doesn't give the same result?

Comment: See above updated answer

Comment: So technically you don't have a _list of named characters_ rather a vector

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

`unname(aa_palette[c("Asx", "Glx", "Ser")])`